# Armadillo documentation not up to date?

Tags: c++, armadillo

I am trying to solve a sparse linear system with armadillo with the following code:

```
arma::superlu_opts opts;
opts.allow_ugly = true; // Error here

bool success = spsolve(*psiV,M_,B,"superlu",opts);
```

According to the documentation, this is the correct code to solve with specific parameters: (http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#spsolve)

```
// Implementation in documentation
superlu_opts opts;

opts.allow_ugly  = true;
opts.equilibrate = true;

spsolve(x, A, b, "superlu", opts);
```

My problem appears at the creation to opts, I get:

```
error: ‘struct arma::superlu_opts’ has no member named ‘allow_ugly’
```

Looking through the files of armadillo / superlu, I found:

```
struct superlu_opts : public spsolve_opts_base
{
  typedef enum {NATURAL, MMD_ATA, MMD_AT_PLUS_A, COLAMD} permutation_type;

  typedef enum {REF_NONE, REF_SINGLE, REF_DOUBLE, REF_EXTRA} refine_type;

  bool             equilibrate;
  bool             symmetric;
  double           pivot_thresh;
  permutation_type permutation;
  refine_type      refine;

  inline superlu_opts(): spsolve_opts_base(1)
  {
    equilibrate  = false;
    symmetric    = false;
    pivot_thresh = 1.0;
    permutation  = COLAMD;
    refine       = REF_DOUBLE;
  }
};
```

Which confirms that I may not have the right version of superlu..

Any one has an idea on how to fix this problem?

I am using cmake as compiler.

Comment: You must have an old version of Armadillo. According to the [list of additions](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#api_additions), you need at least version 9.100 to "allow keeping solutions of systems singular to working precision" (in other words, the`opts.allow_ugly` option).

Comment: @hbrerkere You're right! I have the 8.4 version.  I will look to update my library. Thanks!